# Configuring ubuntu as a root DNS server

Tags: dns

I am trying to configure ubuntu as a root DNS serve but I am not sure what to do. I checked on youtibe for videos or help but no video has been helpful. Any idea??

Comment: Wrong question to ask; Questions need to be about specific problems, not broad. Setting up a dns is going to be a long read and it will be lots of trial and errors. There is a dedicated page on Domain Name Service on ubuntu,com https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns

Comment: Your question lacks context and seems close to an XY problem. A root server is not different than any other DNS server, so it is just a matter of setting up a DNS server, a topic on which you can find lots of resources online, and then if you get to a specific problem you can come back just about it. Even if you will not like that, in most cases "you don't need it". Sure, you can do it, to play and to learn ,and that is very good. But if "in production" you have to ask this question then you definitively don't need it. Please state your real problems to get better help here.